# How to let KDevelop support ROS project?

Tags: ros, ide

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use KDevelop 4.3.1 for ROS Groovy with ubuntu 12.04.

I try to open CMakeLists.txt on KDevelop to open ROS project, but it shows the error that says can't find ros/ros.h.

[image: image description]

How to set KDevelop for ROS properly?

Thank you very much~~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186311/how-to-let-kdevelop-support-ros-project?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-07-12

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-07-13**:
Thank you~ You are correct! When I run kdevelop on bash, the ros.h header is found. Please post it as an answer~^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried starting KDevelop from within a shell where you have sourced your setup.bash?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5